# Conditional expectation of gaussian variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Suppose $$X = QZ + m + V$$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_K)$, $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{M\times K}$, $m \in \mathbb{R}^M$ and $V \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I_M)$. $Z$ and $V$ are independent.

I'm having trouble with one of the steps in a proof for the following expression for the expected value of $Z$ given $X$.
$$E[Z\mid X=x] = (Q^TQ + \sigma^2 I_K)^{-1}Q^T(x-m).$$

The step I don't understand is:
$$E[Z\mid X=x] = E[Z(X-m)^T]E[(X-m)(X-m)^T]^{-1}(x-m).$$

Is there a Bayes rule for expected values I can use? Can someone explain this step to me?

Edit: 
This is in the context of probabilistic principle component analysis. The data points $x$ are modeled as if they originated from a linearly transformed lower dimensional random variable ($Z$) plus high dimensional gaussian noise ($V$). So $M \geq K$ and $Q$ is assumed to be full rank.

Comment: Isn't $M \geq K \wedge rg(Q) = K$ given as well?

Comment: $E[(X-m)(X-m)]$ doesn't make sense, since $X-m \in \mathbb{R^M}$

Comment: Oh I forgot the transpose, it's edited now.

Comment: And you are right, I should have mentioned that this is in the context of probabilistic principle component analysis. The data points $x$ are modeled as if they originated from a linearly transformed lower dimensional random variable ($Z$) plus high dimensional gaussian nois ($V$). So $M \leq K$ and Q is assumed to be full rank.

Comment: $(QQ^T + \sigma I_K)^{-1}$ doesnt make sense as well. $ \in \mathbb{R^{M \times K}} \Rightarrow QQ^T \in \mathbb{R^{M \times M}}$ and $ \sigma I_K \in  \mathbb{R^{K \times K}}$.

Comment: So is $M \leq K$ or $M \geq K$ correct?

Comment: My bad, I should have checked better. That schould be $I_M$. And M $\geq$ K, I got confused with the latex notation (geq vs leq).

Comment: $(Q^TQ + \sigma^2 I_M)^{-1} \in \mathbb{R^{M \times M}}$ and $Q^T \in \mathbb{R^{K \times M}}$  dont multiply as well.

Comment: Waw this proof got me really confused, it should be $(Q^TQ + \sigma^2 I_K)^{-1}Q^T$

Comment: The reason for my confusion was that in the proof they used the identity $A(I+BA){-1} = (I +AB)^{-1}A$. I forgot that the dimension of the identity matrix changes here. And I messed up the transponents on top of that. But now it should be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104183/discussion-between-maurits-descamps-and-grada-gukovic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} T \\ U \end{array} \right] \sim \mathcal N\left( \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ B^T & C  \end{array} \right] \right) \tag 1
$$
where $A\in \mathbb R^{p\times p},$ $B\in\mathbb R^{p\times q},$ $C\in\mathbb R^{q\times q}$ and the big matrix in $(1)$ is positive-definite. Then
\begin{align}
T\mid U \sim\mathcal N\left( BC^{-1} U , A - BC^{-1}B^T \right).
\end{align}

Apply this in the case where $T=Z,$ $U=X-m,$ $A=I_K,$

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
B = {} & \operatorname{cov}(Z, QZ+V) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{cov}(Z, QZ) + {} \cancelto0{\operatorname{cov}(Z,V)\,\,\,} \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{cov}(Z,Z)Q^T \\
& \text{Here the $Q$ gets transposed and gets} \\
& \text{pulled out on the right, not the left.} \\[10pt]
= {} & Q^T, \\[15pt]
\text{and } C  = {} & QQ^T + \sigma^2 I_M.
\end{align}

Comment: Is the fact that $T|U \sim \mathcal{N}(BC^{-1}U, A - BC^{-1}B')$ a well known fact? Is there no intuitive explanation for why $E[Z\mid X=x] = E[Z(X-m)^T]E[(X-m)(X-m)^T]^{-1}(x-m)$?

Comment: @MauritsDescamps : It's a standard result about the multivariate normal distribution. In the case where $(T,U)$ is bivariate normal, it reduces to $$ \operatorname E\left( \frac{T - \operatorname E T}{\operatorname{s.d.}(T)} \mid U \right) = \rho \cdot \frac{U - \operatorname E U}{\operatorname{s.d.} (U)}, $$ i.e. multiply the z-score for $U$ by the correlation $\rho$ to get the expected z-score for $T.$ And the proportion of the variance of $T$ that is "explained" by $U$ is $\rho^2,$ so $$ \operatorname{var}(T\mid U) = (1-\rho^2)\operatorname{var}(T). $$

Comment: @MauritsDescamps : Possibly a posted question could ask how to prove this standard result. Or possibly it's already here.

Comment: I just realized that this is just the minimum mean square error estimate, with the covariance and variance. That's intuitive enough for me.